# iOS bluetooth non-BLE connection

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I'm trying to connect to a speaker using bluetooth. I don't think the speaker is a BLE device so Core Bluetooth will not work. I say this because I have tried to connect to it with the CBCentralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:options: method but it is unable to find the speaker, however I could be wrong. I've looked into the External Accessory Framework but my understanding is that it is only for connecting to an MFI apple device. Just wondering what would be the best way to go about connecting to a non-BLE speaker. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the speaker implements a standard Bluetooth profile such as AV2DP then the user needs to perform the pairing using the device Bluetooth settings app. You can select the speaker as an AV session path once the connection is made.

There are no frameworks that will allow your app to initiate and manage the pairing and connection.